# Click button show div and hide same div after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an email submitting form and when a user submits, I would like to show a confirmation text below the input. After 5 seconds the confirmation text has to fade-out again.

this is my code

```
<div class="input-group newsletter-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email-to-submit">
    <div id="submit-email" class="input-group-addon">go!</div>
</div>
<div id="email-submit-form">THANKS!</div>
<div id="invalid-email-warning" style="color: red; display: none;">Not an email address</div>

$(function() {
   setTimeout(function() { $("#email-submit-form").fadeOut(1500); }, 5000)
        $('#submit-email').click(function() {
            var emailAddress = $('#email-to-submit').val();
                if (validateEmail(emailAddress)){
                    $('#email-to-submit').val('');
                    $('#email-submit-form');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/submitEmailAddress',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: JSON.stringify({'email': emailAddress})
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#invalid-email-warning').show();
                  }
            $('#email-submit-form').show();
            setTimeout(function() { $("#email-submit-form").fadeOut(1500); }, 5000)
    })
});
```

Comment: If none of the answers helped, let us know by perhaps explaining your problem more clearly so we can tray again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$('#email-submit-form').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 $('#email-submit-form').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
      });
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write your timeout logic inside the `if(){` condition or ajax `success`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/submitEmailAddress',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'email': emailAddress
    }),
    success: function (response) {
        $('#email-submit-form').show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#email-submit-form").fadeOut(1500);
        }, 5000)
    }
});
```

Also,

```
if (validateEmail(emailAddress)){
    $('#email-to-submit').val('');
    $('#email-submit-form');   //this line
```

The third line does nothing, remove it.